# generating binary numbers of size n as tuples : itertools.product(*[(0, 1)] * n)

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

- I just found this instruction

  ```
  itertools.product(*[(0, 1)] * n)
  ```

  posted by PAG.

  Can someone explain how it works?
- I am trying to find a way of doing permutations without repetition of n tuples in 3 bags
  and I only can use itertools if I want. Thanks

Comment: `zip(*[iter(seq)]*3)` to split a sequence in groups of 3 for example, is a proper use case of this. `product` accepts a `repeat` parameter which renders this code useless.

Answer (score 4):

`[(0, 1)]` is a list of a single tuple of the numbers `0` and `1`.

`[(0, 1)] * n` duplicates the tuple inside of the list, so we get

```
[(0, 1), (0, 1), ..., (0, 1), (0, 1)]
```

Then, if we look at the `itertools.product` function, we want to pass in each of those tuples as single arguments. So, we use the `*`-operator to unpack our list into arguments to the `itertools.product` function. So, our function is equivalent to:

```
itertools.product((0, 1), (0, 1), ..., (0, 1), (0, 1))
```

which computes all permutations of the `n` `0`s and `1`s.

Note that `itertools.product` takes a `repeat` parameter, which should be used to do this sort of thing:

```
itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=n)
```

---

To do permutations, you can use the `itertools.permutations` function:

```
def pick_into_three_bags(n):
    return itertools.permutations(range(n), 3)
```

Comment: Please note the repeat parameter which renders this code useless

Comment: Thanks but for the permutations I cannot have repetition.

Comment: @user1347096 If you use the function in my answer, it won't give duplicates. For example, the first element from `pick_into_three_bags(3)` will be `(0, 1, 2)`.

Comment: Sorry, This is not what I want, I was probably not clear, and yesterday I couldn't test your solution. If I have elements a, b, c. I want to find all the possibilities of putting these items IN 3 bags, so I should have [(),(),(a,b,c)], [(a,b),(c),()],[(a),(b,c),()] etc...() describing the content of one bag

Comment: @user1347096 Ahh, I see what you mean. Hold on, let me see if there's a function to do that sort of thing.

Comment: Did you find something Xymostech? Thanks

Comment: @user1347096 No, I didn't. :(