# Get a list of all possible binary tuples with length n

Tags: python, tuples, python-itertools

I need a function which returns a list of *all possible binary tuples* with length **n**, like this:

```
binaryTuples(n=2) =>  [(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)]
binaryTuples(n=3) =>  [(0,0,0),(0,0,1),(0,1,1),(1,1,1) ... and so on]
```

I know that this can be done with `itertools`, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
itertools.product(*[(0, 1)] * n)
```

where `n` is the desired size.

Example:

```
import itertools
print "For n = 2: " + str(list(itertools.product(*[(0, 1)] * 2)))
print "For n = 3: " + str(list(itertools.product(*[(0, 1)] * 3)))
```

Output:

```
For n = 2: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]                                                                                                                      
For n = 3: [(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

You can run it live [here](http://goo.gl/Ao39Ri).

<sub>I got inspired by [generating binary numbers of size n as tuples : itertools.product(*[(0, 1)] * n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330105/generating-binary-numbers-of-size-n-as-tuples-itertools-product0-1-n), but didn't mark as duplicate, because it's not exactly what you wanted. ;)</sub>

Comment: Just what I needed, I'll mark it as an answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Using `itertools.product` is the sensible approach here. However, gsamaras` code can be cleaned up a little:

```
import itertools

def binary_tuples(w):
    return itertools.product((0, 1), repeat=w)

print(list(binary_tuples(3)))
```

**output**

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

---

Just for fun here's how to do it using the `str.format` method, which can format integers in binary. The trick is to pass the desired bitstring length into the format specification string.

This code runs on Python 2.6 and later, although later versions can simplify the format spec string. And of course on Python 3 you'll need to change `xrange` to `range`.

```
def binary_tuples(w):
    return [tuple(int(d) for d in '{0:0{1}b}'.format(i, w))
        for i in xrange(1<<w)]

print(binary_tuples(3))
```

**output**

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1)]
```

And here's a generator version:

```
def binary_tuples_gen(w):
    for i in xrange(1<<w):
        yield tuple(int(d) for d in '{0:0{1}b}'.format(i, w))

for t in binary_tuples_gen(3):
    print(t)
```

**output**

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 1, 0)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 1, 1)
```